# Можно ли импортировать весь файл, без экспорта отдельных функций?

Tags: javascript, node.js

У меня есть файл, вот такой:

```
export function showError(title, text) {
    ...
}

export function showInfo(title, text) {
    ...
}

export function showSuccess(title, text) {
    ...
}
```

Импортирую я эти функции вот так:

```
import {showError, showSuccess,showInfo} from './notifications'
```

Все окей. Но мне было бы удобно импортировать сразу весь файл, без указания имен функций и namespace. В глобальную область видимости. Функции используются во всем проекте, так что это не антипаттерн.

Есть такая возможность? Может, какой-нибудь `autoimport autoexport`?

Конкретно интересует node.js. Если есть общее решение для всего js - буду очень рад.

Comment: может, `import * from './notifications'`? Так точно можно: `import * as name from "module-name";` [Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, нет такого синтаксиса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так импортировать или в глобальную область?

---

Если в глобальную, то замени

```
export function doSmth() {}
```

на

```
global.doSmth = function doSmth() {}
```

Не забудь импортировать файл, иначе он ничего не добавит в глобальный скоуп.

---

Если всё-таки импортировать, то можно

```
import * as smth from './smth'
```

тогда обращаться придётся

```
smth.doSmth()
```

---

И ещё костыль, если не используется strict-режим:

```
import * as smth from './smth'

for (let key of Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(smth)) {
  if (key.match(/^\w+$/)) {
    try { eval(`var ${key} = smth.${key}`) } catch {}
  }
}
```

Модули по умолчанию в строгом режиме, поэтому этот код сработает только в том случае, если используется какой-то препроцессор, который превращает импорты в классические require.

Comment: Последний вариант выглядит как код из ада)

Comment: За global.doSomething спасибо, примерно это я и искал

Comment: Превосходный исчерпывающий ответ)